# Skip user and csrf authentication for JSON POST APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

Is there a way to skip require_user for JSON APIs.

I have a web application that sends JSON `POST` requests to my rails app and expects a JSON response. However, each request is being redirected to the login page as (I assume) it is not being registered as having a session.

So far this is what I have:

**memo_main_tester_controller.rb**

```
class MemoMainTesterController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_user, unless: :json_request?
  ...
```

This is where API methods are

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

  helper_method :current_user
  ...

  def json_request?
    request.format.symbol == :json
  end

  private
  def current_user
    User.where(id: session[:user_id]).first
  end

  def require_user
    the_user = current_user
    unless the_user
      redirect_to login_path, notice: 'You must be logged in to view that page.'
    end
  end
```

I got the method `json_request?` from a search through SO, but I don't think it's working.

When I send a `POST` request to the `memo_main_tester_controller` the AJAX request hits a `302` and I am sent the login page with a `200`. How do I stop this and get my expected `JSON` response?

Comment: Couple of things I would look at. First is the `json_request?` code being hit? I usually use a gem called `pry` to debug. Second, what does your json request look like? Can you add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You app should be working on this stage. `json_request?` looks fine too. Thought there is a more generic way to [rewrite it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html):

```
def json_request?
  request.format.json?
end
```

I think issue should be your request URL you call from your AJAX call is not ending with `.json`.

Comment: It was the `.json` ending. Any ideas on why the `require_user` method was not registering as logged in from the json?